# R: How to use dataframe variables as arguments in a function?

Tags: r, function

I have created a code to obtain statistics on a variable and I would like to automate it in a function to use it on other variables.

Name of the dataframe: data
Name of the variable: UNIQUE

Code:

```
  table1 <- table(data$UNIQUE, useNA = "ifany", dnn = "Variables")
  dataframe1 <- as.data.frame(table1, row.names = NULL, responseName = "N")
  dataframe1$N <- as.numeric(dataframe1$N)
```

Now I'm trying to do the function using the table and the variable in arguments like:

```
function1 <- function(Table, Variable){
    table1 <- table(Table$Variable, useNA = "ifany", dnn = "Variables")
    dataframe1 <- as.data.frame(table1, row.names = NULL, responseName = "N")
    dataframe1$N <- as.numeric(dataframe1$N)
    dataframe1
}
```

I tried with the assign and paste functions but I couldn't find the solution.

Thanks by advance,
Pierre

Comment: You need to replace `Table$Variable` with `Table[,Variable]`. When you pass `Variable` into your function it is as an object of type `character`. Subsetting with `$` requires a bare variable name, whereas square bracket notation will accept `character` objects.

Comment: Pass a character to `Variable` and stop using `$`, instead use `Table[[Variable]]`. `$` is for interactive use, `[[` is for programming.

Comment: that's how I do `set_symb=as.symbol(variable); use <- eval(set_symb,Table);` then use use (parsing variable as text)